# Add terms to a taxonomy archive from within the same taxonomy

Tags: custom-taxonomy, taxonomy, archives, pre-get-posts, advanced-taxonomy-queries

not sure if this is even possible (guessing it should be though)...

I have a custom taxomomy of `status`, containing the following terms...

`pending`, `collecting`, `started`, `doing`, `dispatched`, `delivered`, `done`

I would like to add all the posts attached to `doing`, `dispatched`, `delivered` to the archive of the `started` term using the `pre_get_posts` hook.

e.g Visiting `example.com/status/started/` would display all posts with these attached terms

This is what I have (and is not working)...

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'tax_status_started_archive' );

function tax_status_started_archive( $query ) {

  if( $query->is_main_query() && !is_admin() && is_tax( 'status', 'started') ) {

    $tax_query = array(
      'relation' => 'AND',
      array(
        'taxonomy'         => 'status',
        'terms'            => array('started', 'doing', 'dispatched', 'delivered'),
        'field'            => 'slug',
        'operator'         => 'IN',
        'include_children' => false,         
      ),
    );

    $query->set( 'tax_query', $tax_query);

  }

}
```

Point of note: I'm aware I could group all of these posts under another 'catch-all' taxonomy term such as `in-progress`, this would require some reworking of previous code which I would like to avoid if possible

TIA Guys n' Gals

Comment: Try using `'relation' => 'OR'` instead. But, shouldn't that `mop_tax_status` be `status`?

Comment: @SallyCJ ah thanks - will try that when I get in office tomorrow (thanks for the typo catch - applies to this post rather than the actual code - have now corrected)

Comment: @SallyCJ - nope - 'fraid not - thank you for the idea though 

Comment: Can you show your latest code, or did you just replace the `'relation' => 'AND',` with `'relation' => 'OR',` ? And by "is not working", did you mean that the `started` archive page doesn't include posts that are *not* in the `started` term, but are in the other `status` terms like `doing`? So if post A was in `doing`, but not in `started`, the post should still show on the `started` archive page and yet that didn't actually happen?